# EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/root/Library/Caches/Cypress'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos

llevo horas en esto, y no logro instalarlo, `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` pero no instala nada, he agregado `chmod -R 777`, no me salgan con la tonteria de seguridad, porque lo ùnico que quiero es que funcione, he estado corriendo en modo admin pero nada, nose porque sigue saliendo restringido

```
npm ERR! path /Users/ma/Documents/backoffice/node_modules/cypress
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node index.js --exec install
npm ERR! Cypress cannot write to the cache directory due to file permissions
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See discussion and possible solutions at
npm ERR! https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1281
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ----------
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed to access /var/root/Library/Caches/Cypress:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/root/Library/Caches/Cypress'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ----------
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Platform: darwin-x64 (21.4.0)
npm ERR! Cypress Version: 9.6.1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-10T17_30_24_377Z-debug-0.log
sh-3.2#
```

Comment: Según [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55875860/8838721) y [esto](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3081#issuecomment-475934809) puede que `npm install -g cypress --unsafe-perm --silent` o bien `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root cypress` te funcione.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez es el mismo problema